# Zero Division error,float division by zero

Tags: python

This is My code

```
for i in range(len(speed)):
for j in range(len(time_two)):
    new.append((speed[i] - speed[i-1])/(time_two[j] - time_two[j-1]))
```

I get this error:

```
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call  
last)
    <ipython-input-7-9cdf386300d7> in <module>()
      4 for i in range(len(speed)):
      5     for j in range(len(time_two)):
    ----> 6         new.append((speed[i] - speed[i-1])/(time_two[j] - 
    time_two[j-1]))

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Here speed and time_two are a list of floats,
There are no 0's in the lists.

Any suggestions as to what i may change? Any help is appreciated ! Thank you in advance

EDIT:
speed = [14.13102608620676,
 6.111463527087486,
 5.593147106275493,
 4.854037993898749,...]
time_two = [2.0,
 14.0,
 15.0,
 17.0,
 15.0,
 15.0...]

Comment: Please post an example input for both of the lists

Comment: sure, will post it

Comment: There may not be zeros in the list, but you're dividing with the difference of two adjacent items in the list, whose value may equal zero, no?

Comment: There are not zeros in the list, mabye, but you are dividing by `time_two[j] - 
    time_two[j-1]`, which may be zero

Comment: `time_two` has 2 adjacent values of `15.0, 15.0`. So guess what `(time_two[j] - time_two[j-1])` equals when it hits that pair of items...

Comment: Got it,Thank you so much

Comment: I'm a little curious as to why you are performing all of those divisions. What are you trying to calculate?

Comment: I am actually trying to calculate acceleration,which is the difference in velocity by time,but now that i think of it i think there is a problem with how i have calculated time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
time_two = [2.0, 14.0, 15.0, 17.0, 15.0, 15.0...]
```

has two identical values following each other, so if you do

```
time_two[j] - time_two[j-1]
```

you get zero, so

```
(speed[i] - speed[i-1])/(time_two[j] - time_two[j-1])
```

will trigger a `ZeroDivisionError`.